# Appium: Unable to clear and sendKey in pre-filled textbox value in Android 7.0 or above

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, java-client

How to clear pre-filled text box value using java in appium?

I have tried all possible solution available on Internet but not works for me.

I have used `.clear()` and `.sendKey()` both method and it's working fine in Android 6.0 and below version. but it does not working after Android 7.0 or above version.

Here is my code,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.appName:id/text_user_name")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.appName:id/text_user_name")).sendKeys("Automation");
```

I'm trying to automate my android application using below configuration:

Appium-Desktop 1.7.2.

selenium-java 3.8.1

selenium-server 3.8.1

java-client 5.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also ran on this in few occasions, this is not most beautiful code, but works quite good in a pinch:

```
public void clearTxt(WebElement element) throws Exception{
      element.click();
      element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "A"); //select all
      element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);          
}
```

or

```
element.sendKeys("")
```

or

```
Actions navigator = new Actions(driver);
navigator.click(element)
    .sendKeys(Keys.END)
    .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys(Keys.HOME)
    .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    .perform();
```

one of this should be enough...